# Why is XSLT Transform not the expected output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**Environment:** XSLT 1.0

**Expected output:** Only the text node for level 2 element

**Actual output:** Both level1 and level2 text outputs

**xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/section1" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="level2">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="SelectingAndMatching.xslt"?>

<data>
  <section1>
    <level1>hello world 1</level1>
    <level2>unlocked achievement level 2</level2>
  </section1>
  <section2>
    <product1></product1>
    <product2></product2>
    <product3></product3>
  </section2>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing starts at the document node `/` for which you have no template so one of the [built-in template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) is used which does `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, i.e. processes all child nodes which in your case is the `data` element matched by your template `match="/*"` which processes `/data/section1` for which you have no template so the built-in one is used which does `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, i.e. processes all child nodes of `section1` which includes `level1` elements for which you have template so the built-in is used which processes all child nodes, for those text nodes again you have no template and the built-in for text nodes copies them to the output.

Comment: section1 has level1 and level2 elements though and I only want level2

Comment: So perhaps my select should be like this: `select="/data/section1/level2"`

Comment: Yes, in that simple case as you already have the `<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/section1" />` it is best to change it to `<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/section1/level2"/>`. Another solution would be to make sure the `level1` elements don't produce any output with e.g. `<xsl:template match="section1/level1"/>`.